# Concatenating two mysql queries to achieve desire results

Tags: mysql

Here I am trying to show one item per subcategory from a single mysql query. 
This is my table "PRODUCTS" shown below :
[image]

Using a query I am able to show data which I want to get display in a more formatted way. I mean joining table and show data based on id. Image is shown below:
[image]

In this pic you can see multiple items are shown for a single subcategory which is table b. Three items are displayed for a single subcategory "Bag Packs", like wise 12 items are displayed for another single subcategory "Gents Wallets".

I just want to avoid these multiple items being displayed, instead want to show one item per subcategory. 
Using a different query I able to get display the table which I want (shown below) :
[image]

Now the problem which I am facing is how to get his items shown by concatenting these two queries :

**Query 1 :**

```
SELECT p.pid, p.ctid, p.scid, s.name, p.type, p.pdesc
FROM products as p 
    inner join b as s
where p.scid=s.scid and p.type='Gents' and p.featured='1' 
order by name;
```

**Query 2 :**

```
SELECT * 
FROM products 
WHERE scid IN (SELECT DISTINCT scid 
               from products) 
GROUP BY scid ;
```

**"Concatenating 2 Queries"** : This part I really don't have any idea how to achieve. Please help.

Comment: Second query is insane. 1) WHERE clause can be freely removed - it is TRUE for all records. 2) `GROUP BY by scid` combined with `SELECT *` means *return one **random** record for each scid value* - moreover, nothing guarantees that all another field's values in this output record will be taken from the same source record.

Answer (score 1):

To join the results of 2 queries into one result set, use

```
UNION
```

As in

```
SELECT Col1 FROM tableA
UNION
SELECT Col2 FROM tableB;
```

NOTE:  Only one semicolon, after the combined statement.